# why Exception occure in HttpPost?

Tags: java, android

I am sending value through using HTTP-post but an exception occur  my code is as:-

```
public static InputStream SendDetails(String senderEmail,String senderName,String senderPhone,String comment )
{
     if(item != null)
        {
            url = constants.STATEURL + item.getListingid().toString()+"/contact";//?access_token=0|V1CALGARY|e98984a4c954fa1d78e3be626ad81a1d&mode=map";
        }
        else if(itemsavedfromdb != null)
        {
            url = constants.STATEURL + itemsavedfromdb.getListingid().toString()+"/contact";//?access_token=0|V1CALGARY|e98984a4c954fa1d78e3be626ad81a1d&mode=map";
        }
        else if(itemrecentfromdb != null)
        {
            url = constants.STATEURL + itemrecentfromdb.getListingid().toString()+"/contact";//?access_token=0|V1CALGARY|e98984a4c954fa1d78e3be626ad81a1d&mode=map";
        }

        List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token",constants.accesstokenstate));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode","map"));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderEmail",senderEmail));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderName",senderName));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderPhone",senderPhone));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment",comment));  

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        return response.getEntity().getContent();
```

}
 this method called by as:-

```
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            mailHandler myhandler = new mailHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myhandler);
            String mailID = youremail.getText().toString();

            if(mailID != null && !mailID.equalsIgnoreCase("") )
             {
               System.out.println("1");
               ios = SendDetails(mailID,yourName.getText().toString(),yourPhoneNo.getText().toString(),yourMessage.getText().toString());   
               System.out.println("ios-----"+ios);
               String strResponse = convertStreamToString(ios);
                   System.out.println("response"+strResponse);                 
               xr.parse(new InputSource(ios));

                resultmail = myhandler.emailresultdata();

                customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(PropertyDetail.this);  
                customizeDialog.setTitle("Success");  
                customizeDialog.setMessage("Email send successfully");  
                customizeDialog.show();
```

Excepion occure  above code due to which data not successfully send

follwing is stacktrace:-

```
07-03 09:02:15.264: WARN/System.err(491): java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.isReadAllowed(EofSensorInputStream.java:127)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:176)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:516)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:479)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:318)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:275)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at com.rentfaster.home.PropertyDetail.onClick(PropertyDetail.java:1623)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  Method)
   07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-03 09:02:15.275: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
    07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
   07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   07-03 09:02:15.284: WARN/System.err(491):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
   07-03 09:02:15.294: WARN/System.err(491):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
   07-03 09:02:15.294: WARN/System.err(491):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my  convertStreamToString methos is as:-

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Any one suggest me where am I wrong and what's right way to do this.

Comment: Are you performing the HTTP request on a separate `Thread`? An `AsyncTask`?

Comment: no it's inside a methos.

Comment: Are you testing on Android 3.0+? What version are you testing on?

Comment: google nexus 4.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , change your code from

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(ios));
```

to

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(strResponse.getBytes());
xr.parse(new InputSource(input));
```

Comment: sorry this line I write just before putting code on stack overflow ,so it would not be reason of exception...

Comment: After remove this line ,no any effect .Exception is occure.please suggest me.

Comment: Was there any output in the console ? I mean the stream you printed .

Comment: Did the "convertStreamToString" method convert the stream to String successfully ? If so , the stream is closed in the finally block and you can not read it any more . But you can new a InputStream with the String you converted from the original "ios" and read it .

Comment: yes I got converted stream as-   <emails><listing id="36443"><status>ok</status><errors/></listing></emails>

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your input stream to convertStreamToString method and you are closing the same instance of input stream in that method. After that method still you are using same instance of stream. That's why you are getting this exception.

create one local variable of input stream in your convertStreamToString method like below.

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    InputStream inputStream = is;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Try this.

Comment: thanx for your responce, let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Read my blog post about performing network connections on a separate thread. Wrapping the request in an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` usually fixes the issue. It also makes your app much more responsive and less prone to ANR force close dialogs.

#### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: I have read your post ,try to search my problem but unable to get it is any other link?

Comment: create a class that extends `AsyncTask`... perform the HTTP request in `doInBackground`. This is enough to offload the request to a separate thread.